# "Парсинг" блока с поддомена

Tags: php, javascript, поддомены, веб-скрейпинг

Здравствуйте. Есть два сайта: на основном домене и на поддомене. Необходимо отобразить на основном сайте блок, который находится на поддомене. (т.е отобразить не весь сайт, а определенный div). Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Прежде всего, скажите: сервер весь ваш и сайты тоже? Может и без парсинга обойдется....

Comment: @labris Сайты полностью мои. К серверу FTP доступ и MySQL

Comment: Хорошо. А div, который надо отобразить, какую информацию содержит (из SQL или еще откуда-то)?

Comment: @labris Планируется использовать каждый раз использовать разную ссылку, но div нужно выводить один и тот же. Да, поддомен берет некоторую информацию из бд.

Comment: Почему бы тогда не брать эту же информацию из БД на основном домене?

Comment: @labris я считал, что вставить блок из поддомена будет проще. В общем смотрите какая ситуация: Есть 2 сайта. 1-й сайт имеет cms DLE (основной сайт), 2-й сайт не имеет конкретной cms. Всё, что я знаю, так это то, что это aowow (сайт на поддомене). При необходимости я напишу ссылки на сайты, чтобы вы взглянули. На поддомене существует некий калькулятор, на результат которого будет постоянная ссылка. Эту ссылку я хочу использовать на поддомене. Но мне необходима не вся страница (для этого я бы использовал iframe), а только div. Я гуглил различную информацию и там было сказано, что проще парсить п

Comment: поддомен, чем сторонний сайт.